# How to cross validate with a constraint using scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Inputs:

- I have an array `X` of images where each row is an example representing a person.
- Another array `y` for their labels where a label is an integer between 1 and 7.
- And last array of `ids` where the `ids[i]` represents the id of ith person at `X[i]`. (A same person has the same id and there could be different images of same person.)

Is it possible to partition `X` and `y` so that the same person doesn't go into both testing and training set?

I think that I need to use [sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html#sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split). Can someone explain what "stratify" does and is this the right method to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You can use http://yandex.github.io/rep/utils.html#rep.utils.train_test_split_group, which implements the required logic. First argument should be a column with person_ids.

Answer (score 2):

[Stratified sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling) means that `sklearn` will try to match the ratios of classes in your train and test splits to those of the overall data.

What information is contained in your y-labels? 
It sounds that you need something like [LabelKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.LabelKFold.html#sklearn.cross_validation.LabelKFold) or [LabelShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.LabelShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.cross_validation.LabelShuffleSplit) where *label* would be the `ids` in your case.